# libusb: How to retrieve a port number (COMxx)

Tags: c, usb, libusb

I'm using libusb to enumerate USB devices. Now I identified the right device using VID/PID, I'd like to know its COM port number. I could not find the libusb function to be used to retrieve this information.

```
#include "libusb.h"

static void print_devs(libusb_device **devs)
{
    libusb_device *dev;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    uint8_t path[8]; 

    while ((dev = devs[i++]) != NULL) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to get device descriptor");
            return;
        }

        printf("%04x:%04x (bus %d, device %d)",
            desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
            libusb_get_bus_number(dev), libusb_get_device_address(dev));

        r = libusb_get_port_numbers(dev, path, sizeof(path));
        if (r > 0) {
            printf(" path: %d", path[0]);
            for (j = 1; j < r; j++)
                printf(".%d", path[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        if (desc.idVendor == 0xAAAA && desc.idProduct == 0xBBBB)
        {
            // How can I know the device COM port number?? COM12 for instance
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    libusb_device **devs;
    int r;
    ssize_t cnt;

    r = libusb_init(NULL);
    if (r < 0)
        return r;

    cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &devs);
    if (cnt < 0){
        libusb_exit(NULL);
        return (int) cnt;
    }

    print_devs(devs);
    libusb_free_device_list(devs, 1);

    libusb_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider changing the while loop to `for(int i=0; devs[i]!=NULL; i++)` for readability and to remove all side effects for the loop condition.

Comment: Libusb doesn't know about serial ports for some reason.  You should use the library libusbp instead and refer to its `lsport` example (which I wrote).   https://GitHub.com/pololu/libusbp

Comment: @Lundi: This is the sample program from libusb

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Thank you, I'll try that. Why not posting this as an answer?

Comment: "This is the sample program from libusb" Wait are you saying that random open source projects may contain badly written code? :)

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Just tested that, it works fine under Windows thanks. Is it also able to list tty port names under Linux?

Comment: Yes @jpo38, it is cross platform

Comment: Your question requires the use of libusb according to the title and tags and body.

Comment: @DavidGraysonSure, but saying there is no solution with libusb, and proposing alternative library is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score -1):

Based on documentation here:

- https://vovkos.github.io/doxyrest/samples/libusb/group_libusb_dev.html
- https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/group__libusb__dev.html

You can get the port number using the function:

```
uint8_t
libusb_get_port_number(libusb_device* dev);
```

Or, you can open a connection with USB device to perform I/O using one of the following functions:

```
int
libusb_open(
    libusb_device* dev,
    libusb_device_handle** dev_handle
);

libusb_device_handle*
libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(
    libusb_context* ctx,
    uint16_t vendor_id,
    uint16_t product_id
);
```

Comment: libusb_get_port_number does not return the COM port number